# JSONP not working on ExtJS 4 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined

Tags: extjs, jsonp, extjs4

I'm stuck with this code, I'm getting this json formated data from the Youtube API, if I use type:'json' it will fail, because of that cross domain thing but the other elements loads anyway; then, if I change type: to 'jsonp' (which is the syntax described on the ExtJS API) it would give me this error:"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'substring' of undefined" I tried setting type:'anyotherstupidthing' and the same happens, so what could be happening?

Here are my current data model and my store:

```
Ext.define('Video', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['id', 'title']
});

myStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Video',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url : 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc',
        reader: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            root: 'items'
        }
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance! 
Ed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JsonP requires the server to wrap the returned data in a JS function call. The common contract is to pass a parameter named 'callback' to the server to allow for unique names and avoid name clashes on the client.

Calling the URL `http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc&callback=myCallback` in the browser shows that YouTube support this convention:

Ext supports JsonP via the Ext.data.proxy.JsonP proxy class. The reader is a standard JSON reader and *not* JsonP specific, you only need to account for the data structure returned from the server (set `root` to `data.items`).

The working code looks like this:

```
var myStore2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Video',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=surfing&v=2&alt=jsonc',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data.items'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records) {
            Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
                console.log(rec.get('title'));
            });
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

Comment: The code is definitely not working. The proxy's url shows in browser json but not jsonp. So you have to add to url `&callback=myCallback` as you have correctly mentioned before the code. But that's not all. Since you are using `&callback=myCallback` instead of default `&callback=callback` you have to set [`proxy.callbackKey`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP-cfg-callbackKey) to 'myCallback'.

Comment: Did you try to run the code? This is tested code. I *did* run it and it *does* work (Ext 4.0.2a). The callback parameter is added to the proxy url by the Ext.data.proxy.JsonP class. The class also generates the parameter value in order to avoid name clashes with parallel/subsequent requests.